# How to stop owl carousel slider when video being playing?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, owl-carousel, plyr.js

I am using owl carousel slider for video feedback. It's working fine but the I want the stop owl carousel slider when user mouse hover on owl carousel slider and stop owl carousel slider when video is playing.

For video playing I am using the following player:

http://www.bestjquery.com/2016/05/plyr-simple-html5-media-player/

Answer (score 1):

I belive somewhere in your code you setup the player by calling the `plyr` plugin like so:

```
var instance = plyr.setup(document.querySelector('.js-player'), options);
```

Then you can listen for the `playing` event and update bxSlider:

```
instance.on('playing', function(event) {
      $('#BxSlider').data('bxslider').stopAuto(); // Stop the bxSlider from autoplaying
});
```

**[plyr API](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#events)**

**[bxSlider API](https://bxslider.com/options/)** (Check public methods)